# Error:In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font after Glide 4.4 upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, android-glide

I am using Glide 3.7 in my project and I want to update it to latest version because of the performance issues. I was updated Glide from Gradle as described in Glide web site. But after update, I got some errors while Gradle build process.

> Error:In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:font

and,

> Error:In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontWeight

Comment: API Level 26 (or higher) is needed to use [android:font](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can see in the [Glide Documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide#compatibility) :

> Minimum Android SDK: Glide v4 requires a minimum API level of 14.
>   Compile Android SDK: Glide v4 requires you to compile against API 26 or later.
>   If you need to support older versions of Android, consider staying on Glide v3, which works on API 10, but is not actively maintained.